# Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin for Android: missing resource for Xamarin Essentias

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile my solution for `Android` with the template for `Xamarin Forms` in `Visual Studio 2019`. I verified the version of the API of my app and the SDk installed. The error is:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Error]

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths').

`Xamarin Essentials` is part of the template and the version in use is `1.1.0`. I tried to add a new folder called `xml` under `Resources` and add a file called `file_paths.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</paths>
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Please open your project, delete `bin` and `obj` folder in three folders(xx,xx.Android,xx.IOS), then rebuild you project.

Comment: worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Leon Lu You should post your comment as an answer